# Want to install scanner function (Canon MP282 [Pixma])

Tags: printer

I have a Canon MP282 multifunction printer and although printing worked out of the box, scanning does not. How can I make scanning possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Canon provides a Linux driver here:  https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mp_series/pixma_mp282.html?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-822918&os=linux%20%2864-bit%29&language=en